# Rmarkdown not rendering raw HTML

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

After upgrading Rstudio to 1.4 version, when I render this rmarkdown doc

````
---
title: "Raw HTML"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(htmltools)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = F)
```

```{r}
f <- function(text){
   cat(asis_output(htmltools::htmlPreserve(paste("<span style=\"color:green\">", text, "</span>"))))
   return(0)
}
```

```{r}
x <- f('Hello!')
```
````

I get this html doc

[image]

But before the update this code worked as expected, rendering this html doc

[image]

How can I get the second html doc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cat` removes the `knit_asis` class.
You can either avoid `cat` or use `results='asis'` chunck option :

````
---
title: "Raw HTML"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(htmltools)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = F)
```

```{r}
side.effect <- function(text){
   cat(asis_output(htmltools::htmlPreserve(paste("<span style=\"color:green\">", text, "</span>"))))
  return(0)
}

direct <- function(text){
   asis_output(htmltools::htmlPreserve(paste("<span style=\"color:green\">", text, "</span>")))
}
```


```{r}
direct('direct Hello!')
```

```{r,results ='asis'}
x <- side.effect('side effect Hello!')
```
````

[image]

Comment: But, the function `asis_output` is supposed to have the same effect as `results='asis'`, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks, but the function f must return a value that I use for another computation, and, as a side effect, print the raw HTML code in the document.

Comment: See my edit with the two available options

Comment: Thanks again! What I do not understand is why I could be able to do this directly with `cat` or `writeLines` before, without using `results = 'asis'` in the chunck. At some point `cat` and `writeLines` must have been updated to remove `knit_asis`.

Comment: `cat` returns characters which can be interpreted as html with `results='asis'`. To check this : `class(capture.output(cat(asis_output("test"))))`. `asis_output` returns an object of class `knit_asis` , see `class(asis_output("test"))`, which is knitted asis.